# Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ora-00904 in WildFly 10 using JPA?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

I have very weird situation where my application work fine with tomcat when I am trying to make it work with wildFly it throws me the following error only for two entities...

I have done the changes for wildfly,BTW I am using pom.xml so for all hibernate dependency I have changed the scope to provided and changed the JNDI configurations....when I run my application I see many queries running successfully but there are two queries which throw the error. But this error is not seen in tomcat...both the server is using oracle10g

Here is my error...

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   ORA-00904: "PRIVILEGE0_"."APPRESOURCES_RECORD_ID": invalid identifier
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:194)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:791)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:866)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3431)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
>   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:504)
>   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
>   ... 53 more
>
> 17:54:09,067 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./XYZ: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./XYZ: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextLoaderUtil' defined in "/E:/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/XYZ.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/XYZcore/coder/cache/util/ContextLoaderUtil.class": Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
>
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextLoaderUtil' defined in "/E:/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/XYZ.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/XYZcore/coder/cache/util/ContextLoaderUtil.class": Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
>
> at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:231)
>   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
>   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
>           ... 6 more
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextLoaderUtil' defined in "/E:/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/XYZ.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/XYZcore/coder/cache/util/ContextLoaderUtil.class": Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:198)
>           ... 8 more
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
>           at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
>           at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:434)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:186)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:88)
>           at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:682)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1991)
>           at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:550)
>           at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:248)
>           at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:546)
>           at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:133)
>           at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.get(PersistentBag.java:449)
>           at com.XYZcore.core.appRole.ui.ACAppResourceModel.populateDetails(ACAppResourceModel.java:117)
>           at com.XYZcore.coder.context.service.impl.ContextServiceImpl.loadAllResources(ContextServiceImpl.java:86)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.loadAllResources(Unknown Source)
>           at com.XYZcore.coder.cache.util.ContextLoaderUtil.afterPropertiesSet(ContextLoaderUtil.java:45)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
>           ... 22 more
>       Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "PRIVILEGE0_"."APPRESOURCES_RECORD_ID": invalid identifier
>
> after analyzing this I see different behavior for @ManyToMany entities
>   like the column in tomcat is APP_RESOURCES_RECORD_ID and in
>   wildflywhen I run the column for this entity is APPRESOURCES_RECORD_ID
>   you see the _ Is missing in wildfly

NOTE : When I deploy in wildfly there hibernate dependency will be of `<scope>provided</scope>`

Hibernate version which I am using is

```
<!-- Hibernate 4.3.6 core library library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> Uncomment for wildFly 10.0 FINAL --> 
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate 4.3.6 JPA support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> Uncomment for wildFly 10.0 FINAL --> 
        </dependency>
```

Comment: "I have changed the scope to provided and changed the JNDI configurations" - those are the differences, but you don't tell us if a) you're using the same hibernate version in both environments b) what the change in JNDI are - with different initializations/parameters, I could argue for different behavior.

Comment: @OlafKock after analyzing this I see different behavior for ManyToMany entities like the column in tomcat is APP_RESOURCES_RECORD_ID and in wildflywhen I run the column for this entity is APPRESOURCES_RECORD_ID you see the _ Is missing in wildfly

Comment: Any solution? Having the same issue...

Comment: @renanleandrof we changed manyToOne mapping with  mapping table then it worked fine, don't auto generate mapping  tables